# Is there an adjectival form of "alliance"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, derivational-morphology

Here's an example which demonstrates the similarity I'm looking for:

"There is a **corporation** of pilots conducting operations outside of their **corporate** airspace.".

Now, if there is instead an "an **alliance** of pilots", what's a predictable construction to replace **corporate** in the example above?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few, but ***allied*** works best, I believe.

As in ***allied airspace***.

**allied**:

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/allied